# Nested forEach in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want to rewrite this piece of code in terms of streams from Java 8

```
for (Medium medium : sortierteMedien) {
    System.out.println("Fuenf aehnlichste Medien fuer " + medium.getClass() + " mit dem Titel " + medium.getTitel() + ":\n");


    for (Medium medium1 : bibliothek.medienSim(medium)) {
        System.out.println(medium1.toString());
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

The difficulty here is, that there is a `print` statement before and after each inner `for` loop.

Is it possible to rewrite this with streams?

Comment: Yes, but it'll be ugly and counter-productive. Just change the inner loop to `bibliothek.medienSim(medium).stream().forEach(System.out::println)`, if you really want to, but why? It's not really much of an improvement.

Comment: @Andreas: Well, just to gain a better understanding for the stream API. It's not production code. If it is possible to rewrite it, could you please show how? That is, not just the inner for loop but the whole snippet.

Comment: `sortierteMedien.stream().forEach(medium -> { System.out.println("Fuenf aehnlichste Medien fuer " + medium.getClass() + " mit dem Titel " + medium.getTitel() + ":\n"); bibliothek.medienSim(medium).stream().forEach(System.out::pr‌​intln); System.out.println(); });` It's stream code, but just uses `forEach` to do what you did with plain `for` loops.

Comment: @Andreas: Nice, thanks! I didn't know you could have multiple statements in a lambda.

Comment: That's the difference between a lambda *expression* and a lambda *block*. See [JLS §15.27.2 Lambda Body](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2).

Comment: @Andreas Assuming `bibliothek.medienSim()` returns `Iterable`, you can call `forEach()` directly on the result.

Comment: @shmosel True, but I wanted to show OP that it is using streams, so I left it there to be explicit.

Comment: @Andreas Are you implying that `Iterable.forEach()` uses streams?

Comment: @shmosel Hmmm. I guess I *meant* to say: But OP wanted streams solution, so I can't call `forEach()` directly. ;-) Stop confusing me when my brain is befuddled by a cold.

Comment: @de_dust "just to gain a better understanding for the stream API" => once you have a better understanding you'll realise that your example is not well suited for streams.

Answer (score 0):

Imperative statements within loops aren’t typical tasks for Stream API use. You still could do this using lambda expressions without the Stream API, i.e.

```
sortierteMedien.forEach(medium -> {
    System.out.println("Fuenf aehnlichste Medien fuer "
        +medium.getClass()+" mit dem Titel "+medium.getTitel()+":\n");
    bibliothek.medienSim(medium).forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println();
});
```

It would be a different thing, if you want to collect everything into one String before printing:

```
String result = sortierteMedien.stream().flatMap(medium -> Stream.concat(
        Stream.of("Fuenf aehnlichste Medien fuer "
            +medium.getClass()+" mit dem Titel "+medium.getTitel()+":\n"),
        bibliothek.medienSim(medium).stream().map(Medium::toString)
    ))
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
System.out.println(result);
```